# Touches not being registered for the button located at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button located at the bottom right corner of the screen and have touchesBegan method override attached to it, which is not being fired when I try to tap this button (only occurring on real device — everything works perfectly fine on the simulator).

If I relocate it to the center of the screen, it starts working properly, but that's not what I'd want to do obviously.

Looks like the control center recognising stuff messes up with it or something else like it, is there anything I can do to make everything work properly?

Yes, User Interaction is enabled.

Yes, I do need to use touchesBegan.

Comment: Why do you use touchesBegan on UIButton? You should do something like: `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: @mrcfal No, it is a completely custom class. I use touchesBegan and it's siblings to animate the button, while utilizing tap gesture recognizer for implementing actions. And as I said, everything works exactly the way I want it to on the simulator.

Comment: Have you checked with the view debugger in Xcode whether there are any hidden views overlapping your custom button?

Comment: @dr_barto Look, there can't possibly be anything overlapping with the button as it works great on the simulator. The problem only occurs when I try to interact with the app on a real phone.

Comment: stupid question, are you using the same device as your real one as simulator? (just in case it is something related to constraints and frames)

Comment: @mrcfal yeah, iPhone 8 in both cases.